# SQL: how to count how many users got more then 500 images from two different tables

Tags: sql, join, mariadb

I am pretty new to SQL. I am trying to make a simple join query.

For that I have two tables:

1. **First table** `albums` with column name `album_id`, `user_id`* and `album_img_count` (`album_img_count` - column shows how many images belong to an album.).
2. **Second table** is `users` with column name `user_id`*.

*`user_id` are the same for both tables (`albums.user_id=users.user_id`)

**I want to count how many users got more then 500 images total**.

Tricky part - user can have 1 album with 600 images, or 700 albums with 1 image. And both would be valid for our query. Therefor we can't simply count `album_id` or `album_img_count` we have to somehow combine them.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to count how many users got more then 500 images total.

This sounds like aggregation.  To get the list of users:

```
select user_id, sum(album_img_count)
from t
group by user_id
having sum(album_img_count) > 500;
```

Then use this as a subquery:

```
select count(*)
from (select user_id, sum(album_img_count) as cnt
      from t
      group by user_id
      having sum(album_img_count) > 500
     ) x;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it does not have "join" query. I need to use "join" because I will add additional parameters from my `users` table and not only `users.user_id`.

Comment: @En0w1na . . . This answers the question that you asked.  If you have a different question then ask a *new* question.

Comment: Huh? Maybe I am stupid, but you are confusing me. In my question I wrote "I am trying to make a simple **join** query", you provided an answer without "join". But then you say that the answer is correct. Well it's correct, but it has no "join". Is there something I am missing? O_o

Answer (score 0):

Does something like this work:

```
select users.name, sum(album_img_count) as cnt
      from albums, users
      where users.user_id = albums.user_id
      group by user_id
      having cnt > 500
```

Comment: Thank you, sir. It almost worked (except i manually changed `users.name` to `users.user_id` (maybe you can edit your answer). What it did it gave me a `user_id` column and next to it `cnt` count in a list format. However, all I want to know is just one number, **how many users got more then 500 images**. For example an answer would be 7468 users.

Comment: I assumed you had more information in the `users` table than just the id. If all that's there is the `user_id` then you don't need the join as that information is already available in `album_img_count`. If all you want is the final, total count then the sub-select query in @GordonLinoff's answer is correct.

Comment: You assumed correctly. I do indeed have more information in `users` table and for simplifying purposes I did not add additional attributes to the query. Therefore, I do need "join". That is why I am asking how can I get an answer with your SQL example. An answer to "how many users got more then 500 images". That is why @Gordon Linoff answer does not work for me.